# Unhide/Hide a sheet which uses hidden sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a recorded macro on a excel sheet.
I have a button on another sheet to run this macro.
When I run the macro it says the following error.
1642493829920.png

I want to add two lines. First to unhide the sheet where the macro is running and second hide it automatically.

[image]

Comment: Please do not include pictures of code. Instead, paste the actual code so others can copy/paste it if they want to.

Comment: [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Also it is necessary that you explain which line of code is producing the error. • You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). This will solve your issue. The way to go is not using `Select` instead of unhiding/hiding the sheet. You can work with the hidden sheet if not using `Select`.